# Probability related toin coss

Tags: probability

Two coins are tossed independently where P(head occurs when coin i is tossed) = $p_i$ , $i = 1, 2$. Given that at least one head has occurred, the probability that coins produced different outcomes is

(A)$\frac{2p_1p_2}{p_1+p_2-2p_1p_2}$
(B) $\frac{p_1+p_2-2p_1p_2}{p_1+p_2-p_1p_2}$
(C) $\frac{2}{3}$
(D) none of the above

Possible Outcomes: 3(HT,TH,HH). Required Outcomes: 2(HT,TH). So, is the answer $\frac{2}{3}$?

Comment: The reasoning is good but he assumes the coins are fair which is not correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer:

$$P(H_1) = p_1, P(H_2) = p_2; P(T_1) = 1-p_1 P(T_2) = 1-p_2$$

Since the coin tosses are independent,
$$P(H_1 T_2) = p_1(1-p_2)$$
$$P(H_1 H_2) = p_1p_2$$
$$P(T_1 T_2) = (1-p_1)(1-p_2)$$
$$P(T_1 H_2) =(1- p_1)p_2$$

P(different outcomes) $$= p_1(1-p_2)+(1- p_1)p_2 .... (1)$$
P(Head appearing in one of the coins) $$= p_1(1-p_2)+(1- p_1)p_2+p_1p_2  .... (2)$$

Now the conditional probability P(different outcomes/One head has appeared) =

$$ \dfrac{p_1+p_2-2p_1p_2}{p_1+p_2-p_1p_2}$$

That will be your answer

Thanks

Satish